# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/accessibility/R$attr;

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-multidex

I keep getting the following error after trying to run UI tests (androidTest)

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/accessibility/R$attr;

Error:Execution failed for task ':chegg-study:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/accessibility/R$attr;

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/accessibility/R$attr;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/accessibility/R$attr;\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/espresso/accessibility/R$attr;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}
```

My gradle includes the following dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:$espresso"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:$espresso"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espresso"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:$espresso"
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2'
```

- espresso 3.0.1

Please advise

Comment: Any jar files in the libs folder?

Comment: I just tried it on my project and I get this error everytime the `espresso-accessibility` is included. If you don't need it right now, you can remove it to unblock yourself. I suggest filing a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192735%2B

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? I'm stuck in same.

Comment: Yes. It has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by forcing specific libs version:

```
   configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // fail eagerly on version conflict (includes transitive dependencies)
            // e.g. multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are equal)
            failOnVersionConflict()

            // prefer modules that are part of this build (multi-project or composite build) over external modules
            preferProjectModules()

        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
        }
    }
```

and using this gradle command to see the dependencies tree:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies :project_name:dependencies
```